# laravel blade select options are getting all selected

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to mark as selected, an `option` of a `select` element, but they are all being selected.

**BLADE HTML**

```
<h1>value = {{ $entity->field ?? 'this is new' }}</h1>
<select name="field">
    <option value="option_a" @if ($entity->field ?? '' == 'option_a') selected="selected" @endif>Option A</option>
    <option value="option_b" @if ($entity->field ?? '' == 'option_b') selected="selected" @endif>Option B</option>
    <option value="option_c" @if ($entity->field ?? '' == 'option_c') selected="selected" @endif>Option C</option>
</select>
```

If I'm creating a new record, then ***this is new*** is printed in the `h1`.

If I'm editing an existing record, then the option stored in the db is printed in the `h1` (let's say option_b).

So why are all the options getting the `selected` attribute?

**HTML OUTPUT**

```
<h1>value = option_b</h1>
<select name="field">
    <option value="option_a" selected="selected">Option A</option>
    <option value="option_b" selected="selected">Option B</option>
    <option value="option_c" selected="selected">Option C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a logic problem.  It looks like you were about to make a ternary and then decided on a standard if-check, but maybe left some of the logic from the ternary in the code.

This part:

```
 @if ($entity->field ?? '' == 'option_a') selected="selected" @endif
```

Seems to be missing the other side of the `??`, the `:`, and thus will always evaluate to `true`.

Instead, try:

```
@if ($entity->field == 'option_a') selected @endif
```

Comment: the `?? ''` part if when I'm creating the record, I don't have the `$entitiy` set

Comment: OK, still the same issue though.  Try `@if(isset($entity) && $entity->field == 'option_a')`

Answer (score 0):

the selected syntax is like this:

```
<option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
```

so try:

```
<h1>value = {{ $entity->field ?? 'this is new' }}</h1>
<select name="field">
    <option value="option_a" @if ($entity->field ?? '' == 'option_a') selected @endif>Option A</option>
    <option value="option_b" @if ($entity->field ?? '' == 'option_b') selected @endif>Option B</option>
    <option value="option_c" @if ($entity->field ?? '' == 'option_c') selected @endif>Option C</option>
</select>
```